# How to combine two JavaScript statements into one

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I want to combine two statements into one to omit curly braces in conditionals. For example, in PHP, instead of writing

```
if ($direction == 'south-east') {
    $x++;
    $y++;
    }
```

I would write

```
if ($direction == 'south-east') $x++ and $y++;
```

but is there a way to do that in JavaScript? Writing `x++ && y++` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In my opinion and I think most peoples, that is poor style. I think you should always use curly braces when you have multiple statements to execute in curlies.

Comment: Embrace the brackets... brackets are your friends. If not your friend then the friend of the next guy that's trying to read your code.

Comment: If you really have to : `if ($direction == 'south-east') {$x++; $y++}`

Comment: This is why we have braces my friend.

Comment: Aesthetic reasons really, some of us care about it.

Comment: Not in javascript not exactly this. Your two expressions could be rolled into a method call, and you could call it in 1 line. The method would need the braces still of course.

Comment: The reason x++ && y++ doesn't work is that, if x is 0, the conditional will instantly break, since 0 evaluates to false.  But if you wanted to call multiple functions that don't return a falsy value, then you could do if(cond) foo() && bar();

Comment: The problem with all those hack is that they're hacks : they hide the purpose of the code and may hide bugs in certain conditions.

Comment: Well, Jospeh's answer doesn't seem like a hack to me, and as in my code I have many of these conditionals one after the other, writing them in one line saves me a lot of space, and its nicer if I don't have to use curly braces (at least for me), so I don't see the reason of the downvote for my question. It seems there are strong feelings about curly braces around here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Curly braces aren't that bad, but - in very specific cases - you can [enhance your code by using commas](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/):

```
if (direction == 'south-east') x++, y++;
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FY4Ld/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  The statements get executed regardless of the conditional... am I missing something?  http://jsfiddle.net/knMS2/2/

Comment: @Cypher - You've hardcoded `y` to `2` there. It's not actually incrementing.

Comment: @Cypher - Thanks for the link. Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`{ }` that you use does just that - combines statements in one block usable with any flow control statement. You can place entire block on one line - JS doesn't care about whitespace in this case.

Comment: This could be a comment. See others.

Comment: @dystroy, why should I, if it also happens to be an answer?

Comment: I know that, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @LFS, it is single correct answer to your question. You absolutely can't reliably combine arbitrary statements in any other way. Every other answer gives you expression that might work correctly or not depending on its content.

Comment: Just a comment to back up Oleg as this being the correct answer here.  Posting mostly in case anyone else comes along.  All the other shenanigans posted here have potentially catastrophic drawbacks and are ridiculously bad form IMO.  

I think what got lost in Oleg's post is that you can single line with the brackets.  That's what he was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var x = 0,
    y = 0,
    cond = true;

if (cond) ++x && ++y;
```

Note: This doesn't work if x is `-1`;

Or without `if`:

```
cond && ++x && ++y;
```

---

So your code would look like this:

```
if ($direction == 'south-east') $x++ && $y++;
```

Note that the `++` operators is after the variable that means this won't work if `$x` is `0`.

`++x` returns falsy if x is `-1`
`x++` returns falsy if x is `0`

Comment: Use `^` or `+` or pretty much anything without shortcut.

Comment: Like Oleg said, `&&` will break if the first condition is false. You can use `&` and it will check both conditions. Or other operators as stated by him.

Comment: @Shaded - IMHO, a comma is still simpler (as it's not a hack).

Comment: @JosephSilber I agree, no need to evaluate a condition. I didn't know the comma worked like that in javascript and for some reason I couldn't see your answer before.

Comment: @Shaded - I had temporarily deleted it, because [Cypher had me doubting myself for a second there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060505/how-to-combine-two-javascript-statements-into-one/12060564#comment-16106756). We're up and running again :)

Comment: This answer works, but only for the example, not the general situation.